# Custom CMS builder needed for existing ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

I am using ASP.NET 3.5 connecting to a SQL Server database.

I know there are lots of CMS out there like DotNetNuke and Umbraco....but I don't want something like that.

I want something that I can plug into my existing ASP.NET site, something that I can generate some code and just paste it in my page.

You can do this with a company called [Interactive Tools](http://www.interactivetools.com/) and it's basically a CMS Builder. But it only works for PHP sites and I need one for my ASP.NET site.

Any ideas of what I can use?

Answer (score 1):

You're not the first person to ask the question of "[How to add a cms to an existing website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393725/how-to-add-cms-to-an-existing-website)". A few issues you're going to run into when you're dealing with a web forms setup. You're really not dealing with pure static content. Those webforms are all backed by a code-behind which probably is holding sometype of code. If you went with master pages you're also dealing with that combination of code and layout. Simply dropping something in isn't straight forward easy.

I've worked with a number of Ektron installations over the years and what the others are saying here is somewhat true. Ektron uses the idea of content blocks (user controls that display content based on either a querystring value or other type of obtained ID). But with these content blocks,  you can just drop them on a page, select how to obtain the ID and  you're good. The management of the content is anywhere from straight forward to pretty complicated depending on what you as the user wants to do.

Now for the down side of Ektron. It is not cheap. Let me say that again, it is not cheap. You're talking the cost of an average sedan for a full licensed setup of Ektron. Why the cost, because Ektron is more than a 'simple' cms. It's really a full blown solution for total content management. If this is not what you need, then you probably will need to steer away from this.

A couple of suggestions for .net solutions can be found from this question "[ASP.Net cms on an existing dynamic website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323708/asp-net-cms-on-an-existing-dynamic-website)".

Which ever way you go, good luck and hope this information helps you some.

Answer (score 0):

The only product I know of that is similar to that is from [Ektron](http://www.ektron.com/Products/Web-CMS/Web-Content-Management/). You basically drop a web control onto your forms with an associated ID to the content. Then you have a seperate application to manage the content.

---

Now on my personal experiences with this product. The last time I've used Ektron was 2007. Bearing that in mind, this product was very hard to setup and maintain on the administration side. The coupling of it into existing applications was pretty much trivial being nearly drag and drop but everything else that needed facilitated around it was problematic.

It was also very nonperformant. It lead us to an extremely elaborate deployment scheme that we would have to scrape out the html that ektron would render in our staging enviroment and then weave it into our build process so that production systems did not need to query the Ektron CMS as it was too slow to allow.

Comment: Hi Chris. What about now ? Did Ektron become easier and performant ? Is it powerful ?

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question ("I want something that I can plug into my existing ASP.NET site, something that I can generate some code and just paste it in my page... Any ideas of what I can use?") Yes, in a nutshell, from a developer's perspective, Ektron is a ASP.NET Web Content Management System that has .NET Server Controls and an API that developers can use to build cms powered websites, either new or modifications of existing ones. The product has changed significantly since 2007, so for current information, I encourage you to take a look at this technical information as a starting point to get familiar with the framework: http://www.ektron.com/billcavablog/5-Webinars-Every-Ektron-Developer-Needs-to-Watch/