# Let the customer manage their site

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

How can I achieve this?

Build websites ( templates ) and build some kind of 'website manager interface' 
suppose I built website1, website2..

I want that the customer (could be anyone without any programmatic knowledge) can change the site "content" on its on: images, text, title etc'.

Suppose for website1 the url will be www.website1.com (actual site)

And for the url: www.website1.com/admin.aspx
a username and password will be taken and if it validate 
I/anyone with the right permissions will see an interface that through this interface
can change the site content text, header, images and so on... 
How can I achieve that can you point me to an article / example for such?

Comment: yes i figured it up :) so can u or someone explain the ways to build/use one like that? any good tutorial / example that you know?

Comment: look at this: http://webhosting.devshed.com/c/a/Web-Hosting-HowTos/Building-a-CMS/

Answer (score 1):

So you need CMS (content management system). Do you need it for ASP.NET? Then you can look at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243655/what-is-the-best-open-source-net-content-management-system-cms), where you can find links to ASP.NET CMS, for example: Composite C1, Orchard, Umbraco, DotNetNuke and others.

In case of ASP.NET not necessary, you can look at [WordPress](http://wordpress.com/).

**UPDATE:** Which CMS to use, it depends on your tasks and type of cites. I used [Rainbow](http://www.rainbowportal.net/) (I this its development was stopped) and [DotNetNuke[4](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) (but maybe it's too heavy for you). For personal needs I used WordPress.

Comment: i didn't mean wordPress, joomla and alike i meant to write several websites and for each website one cms( that the user will use to edit is own site ).. through asp.net i don't want to use something that is already ready like wordpress and to build the sites through there.

Comment: You mean you want to write your own cms? I don't see why you should do this if there are a lot of cms. You can just install it, customize and then give user some limited rights to modify.

Comment: ok i want to learn how to do that can you direct me to step by step tutorial explaining the installation process cause i dont really know how it works .. i never dealt with that before..

Comment: and also, free one... if exist. Thanks

Comment: okay, you already developed some ASP.NET sites, and just want to add cms possibility for them? Then look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393725/how-to-add-cms-to-an-existing-website

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Sueetie, it has everything you need and more:

http://sueetie.com/features.aspx

The N2 CMS is also worth looking at:

http://n2cms.com/

Comment: thanks for your answer! i don't really know how this is even work how do i use this? how can i combine websites that i have built so that one cms will control them?.. i think i need to start here from the basics.. or i am missing something simple... i thought that i have found what i was looking for here : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvcWeWrEKcI  , but its appear that he didnt finished it.. it goes only to 04 .. can u direct me to tutorial that will explain the build of a custom CMS or maybe i am missing something and can use FREE cms that is already there? Thanks.

Comment: Start from scratch and save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: i prefer to start from scratch i know that if ill just install and use something ready i most likely wont know how it works 100%.. can you direct me to example / tutorial like that one in the url i attached in my comment here?